# Chrome and Firefox can not resolve the same host name, dig can

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

Ubuntu 14.04.

I am on a local domain, xxx.local. From the terminal I can use dig and host to lookup many names served from our local dns servers like zzz.yyy.xxx.local. When I type that same host name in both chrome and firefox, I get ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED errors.

Why can't these browsers resolve these names?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Turns out it's a difference between the way chrome/firefox fetch names and the way dig/host fetch names.

Typical `nsswitch.conf` has this line:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

Which should be changed to:

```
hosts:          files dns mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]
```

and then everything will magically work.

Comment: Nice one. Spent quite some time on that

Comment: You can upvote the question too, since it was the answer to that question that helped you.

Comment: Do you know why this fix works?

Comment: It appears only firefox/chrome respected this line in the nsswitch.conf.  Reading left-to-right, first "files" is checked, if not found, then ".local" domains against a local dns server (if configured), and if not found, then return (stop trying to resolve the name) via "[NOTFOUND=return]".  This is the exact behavior of firefox/chrome.  I had no local dns servers configured ("mdns4_minimal"), my main upstream dns serves the .local requests, and the original line aborts any .local resolution against primary dns servers ("dns").  The fix line searches primary "dns" if not found in /etc/host.

Comment: 4 years later, and this answer is still gold.  Just solved my issue on Ubuntu 18.10

Comment: So what if things like ping myhost.local and ssh myhost.local and firefox can browse to myhost.local but Chrome instead returns DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN and hosts returns NXDOMAIN instead of the ip address?

Comment: @SteveOwens, what's your nsswitch.conf?

Comment: 6 years later, and this answer still solved my issue with Brave.

Comment: 9 years later this answer still works just fine, thank you!